# Python Beginner: How to select key and values from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, nlp

I am working with an API generated json file which contains dictionaries. In the "element dictionary" (inside json file) there is "Path" key and it has a value. Some of the "Path" values are duplicates but I want to make them unique for example by adding /random_alphabets or /random_numbers at the end of the "path" values.
I am using pandas and json_normalize to do this but after making the data frame when I normalize the "elements dictionary" to get the paths, it only displays 50 "paths" (there are 243 paths in the elements dictionary in json file).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('structuredData-15.json') as json_data:
    text = json.load(json_data)
text

test = json_normalize(text)
test

ele = test['elements'][0]
elements = json_normalize(ele)
elements
elements['Path']
```

Following is the link to the json file I am using:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G4eaHRa8IPyGrtQKEa_rbU0CupJih7_4?usp=sharing

I also did this but it is still printing 50 paths rather than 243

```
with open('structuredData-15.json',"r") as json_data:
     text = json.load(json_data)
test = json_normalize(text)
for item in test['elements']:    
     print(test['elements'][0]) #this is printing all the elements including all the paths(243 paths)
for item in test['elements'][0]:    
     print(item['Path']) #But when I select Path, it just prints 50
```

Comment: In your document, there are only 50 items in `elements` key. How did you find 243?

Comment: In my file there are 243 "Path" keys in the elements dictionary. You can find the number of Path by searching it in the json file.